# Add CSS to each RegExp match

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

I need to detect some random regular expressions, and then apply them a style to each one, something like:

- Replace `Match[0]` with `<span class='found'> Match[0]</span>`
- Replace `Match[1]` with `<span class='found'> Match[1]</span>`
- Replace `Match[n]` with `<span class='found'> Match[n]</span>`

I tried this

```
.replace(randomregexp, "<span class='found'>$1</span>");
```

but instead of `Match[0]` showing, it shows `$1`.

my code:

```
 $("#query, article").keyup(
            function change() {
                if (document.getElementById("query").value == "");
                else {
                    texts = document.getElementById("query").value;
                    regexpr= new RegExp(texts,"g"); 
                    document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0].innerHTML = $("article").text().replace(regexpr, '<b class="found">$1</b>'); 
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: are you applying the replace method to the whole html content? can you post a fiddle?

Comment: check the result http://users.ntua.gr/el12507/regexp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `wrap` function. Try something like this:

```
.wrap('<span class="found"></span>')
```

or you may access matched string by using `$&` like this:

```
.replace(randomregexp, "<span class='found'>$&</span>");
```

Comment: thanks! it works with 
.replace(randomregexp, "<span class='found'>$&</span>");

Answer (score 0):

If you could post mode code it would be helpful, but try `.wrap('<span class="found"></span>)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you wrap your match in `(` and `)`. If there is no matched text it'll just show `$1`.

```
texts = '('+document.getElementById("query").value+')';
```

Then $1 should work for the matched substring...

```
'hello'.replace(/(\w+)/,"<span class='found'>$1</span>") 
// Outputs: "<span class='found'>hello</span>"
```

Comment: No problem, I originally posted to use `$&` but then I started overthinking it ;)